# You provided an invalid argument for the where selector for GraphQL mutation

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, graphql, react-apollo, prisma

In my realtime chat app built with React, Apollo, and Prisma, I am getting a `You provided an invalid argument for the where selector on Post` error message during one of the mutation processes.  It works fine when the variable `post` is included, but when it's not included, the error occurs even though it's a nullible variable.

My mutation gql:

```
export const CREATE_MESSAGE_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation CreateMessage($text: String, $image: String, $largeImage: String, $chatterId: String!, $channel: String!, $status: Boolean, $isTyping: Boolean, $post: String) {
    createMessage(
        data: {
          text: $text
          image: $image
          largeImage: $largeImage
          chatterId: $chatterId
          channel: $channel
          status: $status
          isTyping: $isTyping
          post: $post
          }
      )
  }
`
```

schema.graphql exposed to the front end

```
createMessage(data: MessageInput!): Boolean!

input MessageInput {
    text: String
    image: String
    largeImage: String
    chatterId: String!
    channel: String!
    status: Boolean
    isTyping: Boolean
    post: String
}
```

datamodel.prisma

```
type Message {
  id: ID! @id
  text: String
  image: String
  largeImage: String
  user: User! @relation(name: "MessageToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL) 
  chatterId: String!
  channel: Channel @relation(name: "ChannelToMessage", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  status: Boolean @default(value: false)
  isTyping: Boolean @default(value: false)
  post: Post @relation(onDelete: SET_NULL)
  // I've also tried @relation(link: TABLE, onDelete: SET_NULL)
  createdAt: DateTime! @createdAt
  updatedAt: DateTime! @updatedAt 
}
```

Mutation resolver

```
async createMessage(parent, { data: { text, image, largeImage, chatterId, channel, status, isTyping, post } }, { prisma, request, pubsub }, info) {
        const userId = getUserId(request)
        if(!userId) {
            throw new Error('You must be logged in!')
        }
        console.log("post", post)
        // create a message and retrieve the message back for subscription
        const dbMessage = await prisma.mutation.createMessage({
            data: {
                user: {
                    connect: {
                        id: userId
                    }
                },
                text,
                image,
                largeImage,
                chatterId,
                channel: {
                    connect: {
                        id: channel
                    }
                },
                status,
                isTyping,
                post: {
                    connect: {
                        id: post
                    }
                }
            }
        },
            `{
                id
                chatterId
                createdAt
                text
                image
                channel {
                    id
                }
                user {
                    id
                    firstName
                }
                status
                isTyping
                post {
                    id
                    title
                    body
                    price
                    image
                }
            }` 
        )
  // other logic that connects to subscription
  return true
}
```

And finally, the front end

```
        try {
            await createMessage({
                variables: {
                    image: file.secure_url,
                    largeImage: file.eager[0].secure_url,
                    chatterId: this.state.chatterId,
                    channel: this.props.channel,
                    isTyping: false
                }
            })
        } catch(err) {
            throw new Error(err)
        }
```

I thought it was the return from the mutation `dbMessage` was causing the error when it returns the `post` data, but the error persists when even when I take out

```
 post {
     id
     title
     body
     price
     image
 }
```

The error does disappear when I eliminate

```
                post: {
                    connect: {
                        id: post
                    }
                }
```

from the `prisma.mutation.createMessage` in the resolver so I'm guessing it's has to do with the linkage between `Post` and `Message` Type in Prisma, but I can't figure out which `where selector` the error message is point to since it doesn't exist during the createMessage mutation process

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Prisma, but my best guess is that when the `post` argument is undefined, Prisma is interpreting your instruction as "associate this Message with the Post where id is `undefined`". I think it makes sense to omit the `post: { connect: { id: post } }` if the `post` argument is undefined.

Comment: @Brandon that's definitely a possibility. I just find it hard to believe that the one-to-one relationship between two types makes you require the variable no matter what.

Comment: Better choice

`data: {
    post: post ? { connect: { id: post } } : {}
  }`